# Button not widening

Tags: android, xml

I cannot widen buttons on my Android project. I'm only having an issue with one of them.

This is what I'm getting

[image]

And this is what I want

[image]

Only the buttons. Here is my XML for the corresponding issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#4ECDC4"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSignInBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etSignInEmail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSignInEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_divider" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPasswordIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etSignInPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSignInPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPasswordIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSignUpBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivUserNameIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/username_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etSignUpName"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSignUpName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivUserNameIcon"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_divider" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etSignUpEmail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSignUpEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_divider" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPasswordIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etSignUpPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etSignUpPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPasswordIcon"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llForgotPasswordBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etForgotPasswordEmail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etForgotPasswordEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivEmailIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnForgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendPassword"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_positive_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/SEND_PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:width="175dp"
    android:height="55dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnActive"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnInactive"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:background="#AD5BDB"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/SIGN_IN"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnInactive"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnActive"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="#AD58DB"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/SIGN_UP"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlNoInternetNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <include layout="@layout/no_internet_notification" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlPushNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <include layout="@layout/push_notification" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#4ECDC4" >

    <com.cloverstudio.spika.view.MyriadProTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSignInTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/SIGN_IN"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The smaller button is `btnSendPassword` and the other button is `btnActive`. I've tried playing with the widths but nothing changed. I'm fairly new so any explaination why this is happening would be good, so then I know whats wrong if it happens again.Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should align your `btnSendPassword` button with `rlSignInForm` for both left and right...then you will achieve your requirement. Replace the following XML snippet of `btnSendPassword` with your existing XML snippet of `btnSendPassword`...you will get all the problem solved.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendPassword"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlSignInTitle"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rlSignInForm"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_positive_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/SEND_PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: you should not hard code the layout width and height, it can vary device to device with different resolutions.

Comment: that's not my thinking...I just give solution of the problem.

Comment: then you have not given a proper and generic solution !!

Comment: I get your point...and I appreciate your concern. :-) Thanks for your cooperation to be aware that.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:layout_width="match_parent". This should solve your problem.

Comment: That then stretches out across horizontally to both ends.

Comment: Add </RelativeLayout> at bottom. According to above layout xml code you posted, parent is not closed.

Comment: Done. Still the same issue